# Unable to shut down from desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown, lubuntu, lxde

I'm testing Trisquel Mini 7, which is based on Lubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have a minor issue where if I attempt to shut down via the menu, the bottom of the window populates with

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Operation not permitted
```

I am able to shut down via the CLI or by first logging out of the desktop environment and shutting down from the login manager.

Should I be a part of some group?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when installing lxde from ubuntu minimal 14.04.2
To fix this I made sure systemd-shim was installed:

```
sudo apt-get install systemd-shim
```

Then added session required pam_systemd.so to the end of /etc/pam.d/lxdm

```
echo "session required pam_systemd.so" >> /etc/pam.d/lxdm
```

If echo does't work just use your favorite editor with sudo to manually add session required pam_systemd.so to the end of the file.

Reboot and it should function properly.

Comment: I am confused. `systemd` doesn't run in _14.04_. This solution doesn't work in my Lubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.